# PIC Microcontrollers, ambiguous quiz questions

Tags: microcontroller, timer

I am taking a course in micro-controllers (PIC). I recently took a quiz but i am having hard time convincing my teaching assistant that the quiz he made is ambiguous as hell. What would your choices be? And could you comment of the questions themselves?

A little context: The quiz was supposed to be based on timers, it was taken after one lecture on timers and right before the lab on timers.

I am not even sure if i can ask these types of questions in this forum. But i am sure this is the only place i am going to get answers so here goes, be gentle

```
 1. The clock circuit (oscillator circuit) and reset circuit are internal circuits.

    True/False

 2. What is the roll over value of Timer1 when operating in normal mode?

 (a)0x10000  
 (b)0xFFFF  
 (c)255  
 (d)none of the above
```

Note that Timer1 is a 16 bit timer.
Edit: TYPO IN QUESTIONS 2 OPTIONS.

The Pic that we used in our labs is 16F877A. It does not have an internal oscillator.

Answers according to TA were True and (b) 0xFFFF

My choices where False, because you could 'clock' the ucontroller with external crystal, external clock source, external RC oscillator, it did not matter if the second half of the question was true (0&&1 = 1). Mind you we were not formally taught about all the different clock sources of microcontroller.

0x10000 because 255 was obviously wrong, timer1 being 16 bit and because of the fact that the timer rolls over after 0xFFFF.

Comment: Your second answer is clearly wrong because you need 17 bits to represent 0x10000. It is, in fact, the only answer that can not be correct given the information that the timer is 16-bit.

Comment: @Samuel isn't that how timers/counters work. They count to their maximum value, and then they count some more, the extra bit overflows, resetting it back to zero, (some counters even have a pin out to that overflow bit for cascading)

Comment: The timer/counter will have an overflow flag, which works in the same way, but that does not mean you can have a roll over value of 0x10000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that both of these questions are ambiguous. It's not just that they aren't fully unambiguous themselves. There are many people out there who ask sloppy questions, which sound like they're asking one thing, but mean something slightly different. These questions are not clearly different from a sloppy question.

Question 1: The clock circuit (oscillator circuit) and reset circuit are internal circuits.

Scenario A

- Student: They're internal circuits. See, the oscillator circuit is the amplifier inside the chip, and the reset circuit is this beast:

[image: PIC oscillator and reset]

- Professor: No, they're external. The PIC16F877A has no internal oscillator, and when I said 'reset circuit', I meant MCLR circuit, which is external:

[image]

Scenario B:

- Student: They're external circuits.
- Professor: No, they're internal circuits.

Both of these scenarios, while not equally likely, are both totally plausible. The professor does not make it clear that he's not asking a sloppy question.

---

Question 2: What is the roll over value of Timer1 when operating in normal mode?

My problem with this question is that it's badly formed in the first place, meaning the answer he's looking for isn't clear. Multiple choice questions like this are annoying because you don't get a chance to explain your answer. This question could be answers in three ways (all of which would demonstrate that the student fully understood the timer):

Answer 1: None of the above. The timer rolls over *between* 0xFFFF and 0x10000. It's kind of meaningless to talk about *the* roll over value.

Answer 2: 0xFFFF is the rollover value because it's the highest value the 16-bit timer can store. After this, it rolls over.

Answer 3: 0x10000. Because this is the value that actually triggers the rollover.

```
0x0000  - not rolled over
0x0001  - not rolled over
...
0xFFFD  - not rolled over
0xFFFE  - not rolled over
0xFFFF  - roll over happens after this
0x10000  - roll over has happened!  -> 0x0000
```

I can hear someone shouting that a 16-bit timer can't hold 0x10000 because it's a 17-bit value. What they don't realize is that the timer *is* a 17-bit counter. The 17th bit is the TMR1IF bit, which is sticky.

```
bit:  IFEDCBA9876543210    (bit I is TMR1IF)
      00000000000000000  - not rolled over
      00000000000000001  - not rolled over
      00000000000000010  - not rolled over
      00000000000000011  - not rolled over
      ...
      01111111111111100  - not rolled over
      01111111111111101  - not rolled over
      01111111111111110  - not rolled over
      01111111111111111  - rollover happens after this
      10000000000000000  - rollover has happened!
```

---

This is how I would have asked the questions:

Question 1: (Actually, I'm not sure what is the point of this question. The oscillator and reset circuits are implemented partly inside and partly outside the device.)

Question 2: When Timer 1 is operating in normal mode, what is its last value before it rolls over.

---

P.S. sorry if there are any more typos or nonsensical sentences in this answer. Apparently I'm still suffering the effects of the general anesthetic this morning.

Answer (score 5):

1. This is ambiguous unless there is a context of a particular PIC model.  In some cases even that is not good enough and the circuit needs to be known.  Some PICs have only internal oscillators (10Fxxx), most newer PICs have internal oscillators but don't force you to use them.  They can be clocked externally or can drive a external crystal or external R-C.  Some older PICs require at least some external oscillator circuitry (16F877).

   This question is OK if there is a clear context which family of PICs the question is about.  Timer 1 is fixed at 16 bits in some families, so this is valid (within context of such a family).

### Added:

You now say that these questions were assuming the context of a PIC 16F877A.  In that case I think question 1 is a bit ambiguous since at least part of the oscillator circuitry must be external to the PIC.  This PIC can function with a external clock directly applied, can drive a external crystal, or can drive a external resistor and capacior.  The *driver* for the crystal and R-C oscillator are internal, but not the whole "clock circuit".  I think it's not too hard to guess the instructor intended the answer to be "true", but one could argue a case for "false".

As for question 2, that is perfectly fine within the context of a 16F877A and the answer is clearly FFFFh (choice B).  I see no grounds for arguing it was ambiguous or that the answer isn't clearly choice B.

Answer (score 0):

A good quiz will produce a distribution of scores that reflects how well the students have learned and integrated the material. Questions that you might call 
"ambiguous" are often an important part of a good quiz.

I don't teach with PICs, I use ARM Cortex-M processors so I don't know how you are expected to answer the first question. In my course the answer would be true. Are you certain that the answer was not included in a lecture or the assigned reading?

The second question is not at all ambiguous. There are three completely different choices and an option to state that none of the available choices is correct. This should be an easy question if you know the answer. Now, if you can show that the answer was never included in the lecture material or the assigned reading then you have a reasonable argument.

Comment: A question which forces a choice between answers that don't accurately capture the situation, however, is a bad one, since it's not about the technology but about second guessing the instructor's assumptions.  I can describe to you the reality of the clock and reset circuit *possibilities*, but it's unclear how those are supposed to map to the answer choices *in the thinking of the test creator*.

Comment: I agree completely, but the OP _forced_ us to second guess the instructor's assumptions by neglecting to provide any context for the material covered in the quiz. I find that disingenuous and highly suspicious. I decided to assume that the instructor _had_ covered this material and provided appropriate context knowing full well that I wouldn't be giving the OP the answer they wanted.

Comment: I guess I have a lot of problem with an instructor whose desired answers can only be known by having attended their lectures, and can't be figured out by a panel of professionals having both academic background and current practical experience of the field.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Just the opposite, I have no problem with instructors making up questions which a student can only answer by attending a lecture, since it is an incentive to be in attendance and paying attention..

Comment: No, doing that with information that does not have utility beyond class is just playing games.  The point of a technical education is to study the subject matter, not learn to game the instructor's biases.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If instructors were able to shield students from learning the game of biases, the students would be in for a rude awakening when they started in the workplace. I see utility in learning that life is full of arbitrary and non-utilitarian BS.

Comment: @Samuel  old Silicon Valley joke/wisdom: If engineers were running the world, it would run more smoothly, but greater proportion of people would be upset.

Comment: @JoeHass - An important part of a good quiz? A good quiz, should be able to detect the difference between someone who knows how the MCU works, and someone who doesn't. I've been using a range of PICs and other MCUs since 2000, and even I didn't know which answer the Prof wanted.

Comment: @Samuel - This course is about microcontrollers (I imagine), not about life's disappointments, and the questions should be limited to the subject of the course.